# Cannot disable Navigation Bar (or this is something else)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm editing a YAML file today in Visual Studio 2022 and noticed what I thought was the VS Navigation Bar at the top of my screen.

[image: What is this bar?]

I hate the Navigation Bar and always turn it off, so I went into the settings to try to turn it off... again.  But that feature was already unchecked.

I examined the "Navigation Bar" setting everywhere it appears.  Both in the "All Languages" section (i.e. `Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> All Languages >> General`) as well as for every individual file type listed in options.  The Navigation Bar option is turned off for everything.  I specifically examined the YAML file type.  Nope, not there either.  In fact that file type doesn't even have a checkbox for "Navigation Bar" unlike the others.

I tried disabling all of my extensions.  That had no effect.

Whatever this thing is, it has two dropdowns that work.  The one on the right has content, the one on the left does not.  And it only appears when I am editing YAML files.

Does anyone know what this is and how to remove it from my screen while I'm editing YAML files?

Comment: I have the same exact issue, the Navigation bar cannot be removed in Visual Studio 2022 it seems, probably a bug.

Comment: I reported it to Microsoft but they (reasonably, I think) decided it wasn't really worth fixing.   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Navigation-Bar-settings-is-not-honored-f/1637059